# return to previous view and show error where ModelState.IsValid is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one problem, in asp.net mvc, I create one view for create user with this url (rout)

mydomain.com/create/users/pos/voot

I create this url with rout and redirect this url to insert action.
now i want when ModelState not IsValid return back to the view and show error message, I want in back , contetnt of textbox not clean and display the data was entered.
How  can do it?
I do this scenario like this code

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

and in view

```
    foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
        {
            Response.Write(error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

but my textbox content clean and error does not display.

Answer (score 4):

So your controller that takes in the post request will look something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // model is valid, proceed.
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        // This returns to the view with the errors
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: And in your view, display the validation messages.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger thanks for yout answer,but i can't do it, becausei use rout ,and when i do it i redirect to mydomain.com/create/users,but i want redirect to mydomain.com/create/users/pos/voot